# Edition upgrade on SQL Server failover clustered instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, clustering, installation, failover

We did Edition upgrade on our active node for the SQL Server instance SQL01 and that was successful.

I have a question/doubt --> Do I need to proceed the same on other node as well since SQL Server or its binaries were installed on passive node too?

If yes, which I assumed and tried to test and went ahead with checking what it shows when I start up the set up:

It takes me all the way to same screen where instance name is selected after selecting edition upgrade under maintenance and I am confused if the upgrade was success on active node?

Please suggest how does the upgrade of edition works on 2 node cluster with SQL Server FCI?

Thanks

Comment: Yes you can. As long as you make sure you stop at any errors. [SQL Server Rolling upgrade- Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/958734/sql-server-failover-cluster-rolling-patch-and-service-pack-process) ideally, you should test failover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, unlike Service Packs and Cumulative Updates where you're responsible to keep the bits in the same state across all nodes, the Edition upgrade applies to both nodes at once. I applied it myself to the 'passive' node and Configuration Manager on the active node showed Enterprise immediately. You still need to restart the service though, as SSMS showed Standard in Properties even after refreshing and reconnecting, but immediately reflected Enterprise after refresh once I'd restarted the service.

Comment: Per docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/upgrade-to-a-different-edition-of-sql-server-setup?view=sql-server-2017